# PHP Warning: include_once() failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an include in PHP.
The weird thing is that I have a copy of the file I'm including, if I include the original file the there is no problem, but if I include the copy then the error shows up.

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(index2.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in "path"/index.php on line 30
PHP Warning:  include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'index2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in "path"/index.php on line 30
```

The original file is index2.php.bck, if I switch the names between the files, then the error disappears. The permissions are the same for both files (644) and I've already tried to add `dirname(__FILE__)` without success.

I have to say that the copy has a different html code, but the only thing that changes is the body.

Comment: If you run `ls -l` do you get see a '+' after the permissions? do they both have the same owner and group?

Comment: @DAB thanks for the reply. I have found the problem, it was because the context was different. It had the original context instead of `httpd_sys_content_t`.